# Virtualbox won't install

Tags: virtualbox, slackware

I have recently installed Slackware 14.2. I wanted to install Virtualbox and I'm sure I've installed most dependencies, but when I try to install virtualbox-kernel I get this:

```
bash-4.3# installpkg virtualbox-kernel-5.0.40_4.4.88-x86_64-3_slonly.txz 
Verifying package virtualbox-kernel-5.0.40_4.4.88-x86_64-3_slonly.txz.
Installing package virtualbox-kernel-5.0.40_4.4.88-x86_64-3_slonly.txz:
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
# virtualbox-kernel (VirtualBox kernel module)
#
# This is the supplementary kernel driver for the VirtualBox
# virtualisation environment.
#
# Homepage: https://www.virtualbox.org
#
Executing install script for virtualbox-kernel-5.0.40_4.4.88-x86_64-3_slonly.txz.
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/4.4.88/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/4.4.88/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Package virtualbox-kernel-5.0.40_4.4.88-x86_64-3_slonly.txz installed.
```

So virtualbox won't start VMs, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the result of executing `uname -a`?

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that you are running the 32-bit version of Slackware, and you are attempting to install a 64-bit application.

Another possibility is that you need to install the Slackware packages that contain the source and/or headers (usually kernel-devel or kernel-source or kernel-headers, been a while since I ran Slackware).

Comment: Can you simplify that for me? I don't understand what I'm supposed to do

Comment: Please send output of `uname -a`.

Comment: The output of the uname command will show your kernel release and machine. If you only installed the 32-bit version of Slackware the machine will be something like i686 instead of x86_64. In which case, the 64-bit of VBox will not work. Or you may just be missing the kernel-modules package.

Comment: Also send output of `slackpkg file-search modules.builtin`